# OpenAPI/Swagger spec for OAuth 2 Authorization code flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, swagger-2.0, openapi

Is there are good open source Swagger 2.0 spec for OAuth 2 Authorization code flow that I could use in my project? Or a swagger spec for OpenID Connect flow.

Comment: Check this on Discovery https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/

Comment: @KavinduDodanduwa i was looking for OpenAPI spec, not OIDC discovery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own OpenAPI spec for endpoints used in OAuth2 Authorization Code grant: https://github.com/fed239/oauth2-swagger/blob/master/oauth2-authorization_code.yaml